# Парсер с сайта в excel

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic, макросы

У меня есть макрос

```
Function GetHTTPResponse(ByVal sURL As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With oXMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        GetHTTPResponse = .responseText
    End With
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function

Function TNVED(Code As String, Poshlina As String)
    url = "https://www.alta.ru/tnved/code/" & Code & "/"
    Text = GetHTTPResponse(url)
    StartText = "description"
    Start = InStr(1, Text, StartText) + Len(StartText) + 20
    TNVED = Mid(Text, Start, 200)
End Function
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        frm = Range("D1").Text
        If frm <> "" Then
            If InStr(frm, "Базовая ставка таможенной пошлины:") > 0 Then
                frm = Mid(frm, InStr(frm, "Базовая ставка таможенной пошлины:") + Len("Базовая ставка таможенной пошлины:"))
            Else
                Range("B1").Value = "Нет данных"
            End If

            Range("B1").Value = Trim(Split(frm, ",")(0))    'извлечение числа после двоеточия до запятой

            If Range("B1").Value = "" Then Range("B1").Value = "Нет данных"
            
        Else
            Range("B1").Value = "Отрезок не найден"
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Он парсит с сайта пошлину по коду тн вэд. Вводится в ячейку А1 код тн вэд, а в ячейку D1 формула =TNVED(A1;A1) и в ячейке B1 выводится пошлина по этому коду. Сегодня в один момент после проверки кода появилось следующее в ячейках B1 и D1

```
set="UTF-8">
    <title>Альта-Софт</title>

    <script>
      function callback(token) {
        console.log(callback);
      }
    </script>

<style>
.container{margin-top: 100px !important; width:
```

с чем это может быть связано? как это можно исправить?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности: «проблема с/в …» — это плохой заголовок.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin поправил)